# Ordered and repeated flags using argparse

Tags: python, command-line-interface, argparse

Trying to implement a CLI using argparse without writing my own parser if possible. Basically I would like to use the command line in order to invoke different methods sequentially in a program, i.e.:

`my_program.py --doA --doB --doA --doA`

I've seen threads with good ideas on how to obtain ordered arguments, but I suppose I would end up with a list like this `['doA', 'doB', 'doA', 'doB']` where I would still need to parse the arguments myself.

Is there any way to exploit tools in argparse in order to help execute these commands in order? Thanks!

Comment: `argparse` is not suitable for that kind of parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a parser that will collect these arguments repeatedly and in order:

```
In [1]: import argparse                                                         
In [2]: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()                                      
In [3]: parser.add_argument('--doA', dest='cmd', const='doA', action='append_con
   ...: st');                                                                   
In [4]: parser.add_argument('--doB', dest='cmd', const='doB', action='append_con
   ...: st');
```

test:

```
In [5]: args = parser.parse_args('--doA --doB --doA --doA'.split())             
In [6]: print(args)                                                             
Namespace(cmd=['doA', 'doB', 'doA', 'doA'])
```

do something:

```
In [7]: for action in args.cmd: 
   ...:     print('action:', action) 
   ...:                                                                         
action: doA
action: doB
action: doA
action: doA
```

If I had defined:

```
def doA(*args):
   # do something
   pass
```

and used `const=doA`, then the `args.cmd` list would be

```
Namespace(cmd=[doA, doB, ...])
```

and we could write

```
for action in args.cmd:
    action(arguments)
```

`argparse` docs has something like this for subparses and the `set_default` command.

If these are the only arguments you accept this would be over kill.  But if there are other options that need `argparse` this would fit in.  But accepting a

```
parser.add_argument('--cmd', nargs='*', ...)
```

would be fine.  It could use `choices` to restrict the input strings, and even a `type` function to translate the strings into function objects.

Answer (score 0):

Command line arguments can separated into 3 groups:

1. Options - prefixed by `-` or `--` and usually specify how the command should behave (`--verbose`) and may or may not take values, and typically the order does not matter
2. Sub commands - are one of a few program defined keywords telling to program to perform a certain subset of the program's full suite of functionality (`pull` in `git pull`), usually only one can be specified at a time
3. Arguments - Are the values usually passed at the end of the command, and specify the values to use during execution, and typically these values are simply consumed without any modification

Most argument parsers treat options as unordered and tend to simply set values to variables or properties in a namespace for the programmer to use. This makes ordered options generally not possible without writing a custom parser.

For your tool you just want to specify an ordered list of actions to take, so it might make more sense to pass them in as either values to an option, or simple arguments.

```sh
my_program.py --actions doA doB doC doD
my_program.py doA doB doC doD
```

Argparsers (like python's [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html)) do not mutate the values given to options or values passed as arguments, meaning the order of the actions would be preserved.